# jquery load not able to send data values to asp.net page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am sending data values from jquery load method from "ajax.aspx" page like this to the "gridViewPage.aspx". The code of "ajax.aspx" page is -

```
 $("#gridViewDiv").load("gridViewPage.aspx", { "productName": "Bat" }, function (response, status, xhr) {
 });
```

In gridViewPage.aspx.cs page the code is -

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string productName = Request.Form["productName"];
}
```

In the gridViewPage.aspx.cs i am getting null for productName ? why it is happening?

If i use an html page instead of "ajax.aspx" then productName gives "Bat". Why it is not working for aspx page ?

**UPDATE** - I find this [solution](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/293/request-form-is-empty-when-posting-to-aspx-page). The problem is due to friendly url. However i could not find the proper solution because in my website there is no 
global.asax nor RegisterRoutes class. So what should i do now ?

Comment: It is working fine on mine end. I just created two page and check your things without masterpage

Answer (score 0):

Please try without form

```
 string productName = Request["productName"];
```

Now webform will try to look in every collection

Your code is working well as I made this change in gridviewpage.aspx like this

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.Form["ProductName"] != null)
            {
                Response.Write(Request.Form["ProductName"] + "  is postback check");
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Comment: infact no need for Response.End();